# Autoscaling : Minimum 2 Instances and a subsequent Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, autoscaling

All,

Am really stuck and have tried almost everything. Can some one please help.

I provision 2 instances while creating my Auto-scaling group. I trigger a Lambda ( manipulates the tags) which changes the instance name to a unique name.

**Desired State**
I want first instance of Lambda to give first instance the name "web-1"
Then second instance of lambda would run just fine to assign a name "web-2"

**Current State**
I start with a search on running instances to see if "web-1" exists or not. 
So in this case my Lambda executes twice and creates both instances with the same name ( web-1, web-1).

How do I get around this ? I know that the problem is due to Lambda listening to Cloud Watch events. ASG Launch creates 2 events at the same time in my case leading to the problem I have.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a launch index value in the data available to your Lambda function? I haven't checked this with Autoscaling Groups but in general if you launch multiple EC2 instances with a single API command they will each get a different launch index value which can be used for the type of unique naming you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Mark,  ASG unfortunately does not allow you to index the instances which it creates. Hence I am left with no choice but to start both the instances with a tag "web-0". Later on I rename them using my Lambda. If only I could add a delay of 2 minutes between my 2 instances, that also would do the trick. Seems all the options are currently not available.

Comment: What do you wish to do when `web-1` is later terminated and another instance is launched? Should the new instance become `web-1`, or should it become `web-3`?

Comment: It would get web-1 as its name. Only if web-1 is not available, web-3 would be assigned to the instance tag. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a classic multi-threading issue. Both lambda functions execute simultaneously, see the same "unused" `web-1` and mark both with the same function.

What you need is an atomic operation that gives each Lambda execution "permission" to proceed. You can try using a helper DynamoDB table to serialize the tag attempts.

1. Have your lambda function decide which tag to set (web-1, web-2, etc.)
2. Check a DynamoDB table to see if that tag has been set in the last 30 seconds. If so, someone else got to it first, so go back to step 1.
3. Try to write your "ownership" of your sought-after tag to the DynamoDB along with your current timestamp. Try using some `attribute_not_exists` or other DynamoDB conditions to ensure only one simultaneous such write succeeds.
4. If you fail at writing, go back to step 1.
5. If you succeed at writing, then you're free to set your tag.

The reason for the timestamps is to allow for "web-1" to be terminated, and then having a new EC2 instance launched and labelled "web-1".

*The above logic is not proven to work, but hopefully should give enough guidance to develop a working solution.*

Comment: Thanks Matt. I shall for sure try this. Meanwhile I have got Lambda working by adding a time.sleep(random) right at the beginning of the handler. Unless both the random return the same number ( which is very rare) I should be good. Important thing to note is that my scaling policy always adds 1 instance. So I will not encounter multi-threading challenge which I face while provisioning ASG. Could you and others please comment on this approach ?